# SwapBuffers getting slow over time

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I'm using multithreaded OpenGL to render into a window.
If I press a button, a model will be rotated for 5sec. After this rotation I print out the FPS. The rest of the time OpenGL is doing nothing.
The model will not be changed over time and all threads are paused while rotating.
At the beginning I have 240FPS after 30 times using this Button (and also waiting until everything finished moving) my FPS drops down to 30FPS (looks realy slow).

My loop is looking like this, I also tryed other combinations like deleting glFlush and glFinish.

```
pDriverOpenGL->Lock();
pDriverOpenGL->Present(this); //drawcall
glFlush();
glFinish();
//glFlush(); 
SwapBuffers(hdc);
pDriverOpenGL->Unlock();
```

Do I miss some command?
I also read, that GL commands are stacked onto a buffer until glFlush is called. Is that true?
Can someone pls discribe me how this stack is working? and how can I clear it?

btw, I'm using windows 10, AMD Radeon R7 M370

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This code alone is not enough to tell you what is wrong. We need the draw call as well as the lock and unlock. You might have a leak or slow operations in those.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! with TechPowerUp GPU-Z I checked the GPU memory, and also the Taskmanager does not change memory... so there is no memory leak. I can not print the code here, it is very huge and not easy to go into... (it is a ready projekt, which works with DirectX 11 and I have to write a OpenGL driver for working on Linus OSX...)

Comment: But maybe you know more about some kind of stackbuffer for storing openGL commands until glFlush is called. This would help me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake...
Inside "pDriverOpenGL->Present(this);" I'm using

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
```

after every call of "GetDC" the command getting somehow slower. Now I only call it 1 time and save the HDC as a Member

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

@ locking I do InitializeCriticalSection(&m_CS); And yes I'm sure there is only one Thread drawing

I assume your code above is in a loop and you are creating everytime a critical section, are you deleting it? BTW: You should create the critical section one time and use EnterCriticalSection/LeaveCriticalSection in Lock/Unlock.

Comment: On linux there is no critical section type per se. His port would have used something like either a spin lock or a posix mutex most likely. As ``Lock()`` is a member function of the GL driver he wrote, I would consider it unlikely that he would not initialize the synchronization instance in the class' constructor.

Comment: ahh sorry... I use EnterCriticalSection(&m_CS) not  InitializeCriticalSection(&m_CS)...

Comment: InitializeCriticalSection(&m_CS) I only use at the beginning